# How to update a datarow in datatable by getting rowindex of datatable object?

Tags: c#

Basically, what I need to do is update a record in my datatable without knowing what the row index is. So I get the row index by searching the value in the columns of the datatable.

I have searched over the internet but I can't understand why the code I have now only updates only the FIRST record in the datatable even when the value I'm searching for it is in the second row. What am I doing wrong?

```
    private void SaveBtn__Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (SUpdateReq_Grd.SelectedRows.Count > 0)
        {
            if (MySkills_dataTable.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                 string SkillID = SkillID_Txt.Text;
                 string Proficiency = Proficiency_Cmb.SelectedItem.ToString();
                 string Yrs_Exp = YrsExperience_cmb.SelectedItem.ToString();

                 //find rowIndex of skill id    
                 DataRow[] Rows = MySkills_dataTable.Select("SkillID='"+ SkillID + "'");

                MySkills_dataTable.Rows[0]["Proficiency"] = Proficiency;
                MySkills_dataTable.Rows[0]["Yrs_Experience"] = Yrs_Exp;

                MySkills_dataTable.AcceptChanges();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: What event does this code that you are displaying reside in..? you want to look at the e.....Arguments and Selected by getting at the cells, row .selected.. this is just a sudo explanation but would like to see the true method / event you are in

Comment: Don't you mean to update the selected Rows[0] rather than MySkills_dataTable.Rows[0]?

Comment: @DJKRAZE What should it not be hard coded? SkillID is a variable and I am trying to get the row where it is in. And get the index

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you should use your `Rows` variable to set the new values on, and not the complete datatable:

```
//find rowIndex of skill id    
DataRow[] Rows = MySkills_dataTable.Select("SkillID='"+ SkillID + "'");

Rows[0]["Proficiency"] = Proficiency;
Rows[0]["Yrs_Experience"] = Yrs_Exp;
```

Comment: This is correct solution, however if `Rows` return more than one datarow, only first row will be updated.